# RegEx in python is testing fine, but not implementing properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a personal project and this is my first time using RegEx, so forgive me if I've misunderstood the documentation. In my program I am reading a webpage and trying to parse information from it. I've tested my expression at pythex [(link)](https://pythex.org/?regex=%2C%5Cd%5Cd%2C&test_string=291230%2C1619%2C43801314%20426005%2C77%2C1526319%20324883%2C80%2C2064954%20669155%2C76%2C1440237%20320402%2C91%2C5933387%20144963%2C99%2C13040711%20380507%2C70%2C743124%20387592%2C84%2C3119589%20151260%2C91%2C6150297%20703369%2C64%2C413056%20599216%2C63%2C393779%20195668%2C80%2C2096232%20191977%2C82%2C2540831%20326908%2C70%2C748218%20709559%2C51%2C113909%20405685%2C67%2C547977%20572221%2C48%2C83492%20443568%2C65%2C456357%20325912%2C60%2C273874%20436817%2C70%2C789871%20364612%2C58%2C232633%20314387%2C50%2C106976%20184820%2C71%2C853614%20378565%2C52%2C131877%20-1%2C-1%20-1%2C-1%20-1%2C-1%20401271%2C17%20-1%2C-1%20218157%2C8%20610933%2C1%20319030%2C7%20247208%2C1%20-1%2C-1&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), and it accurately highlights the part of the string I'm interested in, yet when I test the code with the same input in my command line, I get a strange output.

I've tried using search, findall, and match with varying strange outputs, but no luck.

```py
def getStats():
    playername = input("Enter your OSRS name: ")
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=" + playername) as response:
            page = response.read()
            page = str(page)
            levels = re.findall(r'[,\d\d,]', page)
            print(levels)
```

This is the section of code that I want to parse the digits from the webpage and store them in a list. If you look at my pythex link, the output should be

```
Output: ['77', '80', '76', '91', ...
```

Instead, the output I get is

```
Output: ['2', '9', '1', '2', '2', ...
```

Any glaring issues with the code I've posted? I assume something is wrong with the way I've written my expression in python.

Comment: It's better if you provide a sample player name.

Comment: The player name that returns the data used in my pythex link is 'arayvenn'

Comment: You have specified \d as a character class. Instead you should specify it as a pattern. Something like r”\d{2}”. There is no sub for reading and understanding the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the square brackets in your expression -- these are for character classes and mean 'only one of these characters'.  Your `[,\d\d,]` expression actually means 'a comma or a digit or a digit or a comma'.

What you need is parentheses for capturing groups: `r',(\d\d),'`

Example on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/FoaKZL/1

For more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
re.findall('(?<=,)\d{2}(?=,)', page)
```

#### output:

```
['77', '80', '76', '91', '99', '70', '84', '91', '64', '63', '80', '82', '70', '51', '67', '48', '65', '60', '70', '58', '50', '71', '52']
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://regex101.com here's an example on how to achieve that in Python and how to obtain only the numbers (not the commas)

```py
import re

regex = r",(\d\d),"

test_str = "291230,1619,43801314 426005,77,1526319 324883,80,2064954 669155,76,1440237 320402,91,5933387 144963,99,13040711 380507,70,743124 387592,84,3119589 151260,91,6150297 703369,64,413056 599216,63,393779 195668,80,2096232 191977,82,2540831 326908,70,748218 709559,51,113909 405685,67,547977 572221,48,83492 443568,65,456357 325912,60,273874 436817,70,789871 364612,58,232633 314387,50,106976 184820,71,853614 378565,52,131877 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 401271,17 -1,-1 218157,8 610933,1 319030,7 247208,1 -1,-1"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```